# How to parse Pyrebase OrderedDict

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Pyrebase get() method returns a OrderedDict and I was wondering how would I parse it to get the value.

Here's how and when I use Pyrebase's get() method:

```
 pyre_game = db.child("games/data").order_by_child("id").equal_to(
                                    game_object).limit_to_first(1).get()
```

And when I call

```
pyre_game.val()
```

This is what I get: Here's what I get in the console:

```
OrderedDict([('-LKYjwhuEMjwadDcfWAl', {'category': 'Main game', 'cover': {'cloudinary_id': 'eohx6zgumfvvjlqgaac6', 'url': '//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/eohx6zgumfvvjlqgaac6.jpg'}, 'developers': [16083], 'first_release_date': 1532563200000, 'genres': [9, 14, 32], 'id': 105176, 'name': 'Arcane Golf', 'platforms': [6], 'release_dates': [{'category': 0, 'date': 1532563200000, 'human': '2018-Jul-26', 'm': 7, 'platform': 6, 'region': 8, 'y': 2018}], 'screenshots': [{'cloudinary_id': 'tgdsmj4ybqndrq9xrxe7', 'url': '//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/tgdsmj4ybqndrq9xrxe7.jpg'}, {'cloudinary_id': 'ryxzsrfw8zrlfa1fwuxz', 'url': '//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/ryxzsrfw8zrlfa1fwuxz.jpg'}, {'cloudinary_id': 'krlxlyg3r46w3mrsrozx', 'url': '//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/krlxlyg3r46w3mrsrozx.jpg'}, {'cloudinary_id': 'xkofnlley4atbqbpc4em', 'url': '//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/xkofnlley4atbqbpc4em.jpg'}, {'cloudinary_id': 'atr178vq39rcksei1bhd', 'url': '//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/atr178vq39rcksei1bhd.jpg'}, {'cloudinary_id': 'qo8znn18apizvlzbzec5', 'url': '//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/qo8znn18apizvlzbzec5.jpg'}], 'summary': 'Arcane Golf is a miniature golf puzzle game set in a fantasy world full of dungeons, dangers, gems, and geometry. Play across 200 levels set in 4 unique courses inspired by classic adventure games!', 'updated_at': 1533116562596, 'videos': [{'name': 'Trailer', 'video_id': 'khDsYapla0M'}], 'websites': [{'category': 8, 'url': 'https://www.instagram.com/gold5games'}, {'category': 5, 'url': 'https://twitter.com/Gold5Games'}, {'category': 13, 'url': 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/897800'}]})])
```

How would I go to parse to get the value. The value is everything inside {} It starts with a category object

Comment: An ordered-dict work's exactly like a dict with respect to getting and setting values, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work

```
for x in pyre_game.each():
    print( x.key(), x.val() )
```

Comment: God bless your family

Comment: Thank you , And bless yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can also alternatively typecast the OrderedDict and use it like a dictionary.

```
pyre_game = dict(db.child("games/data").order_by_child(game_object).limit_to_first(1).get().val()) 
print(pyre_game)
```